# How to use hyperlink in web application?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, hyperlink

I am developing a web-based application. I want to save a hyperlink of some related files to my database and open them when users need it. I can open files using asp.net with below code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

But I can't save file path into the database because for security reasons `<input type="file"/>` does not provide the full path of the file.

Do you know any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Using absolute path can lead to major issues during migration. Instead use relative path (_start from the base directory_) which you can store in DB and retrieve that path from the Webapp Code

Comment: @sonny can you please provide your suggested code?

Comment: I dont know exactly what you want to display. This [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/438676/get-url-from-database-and-display-image-in-file-sy) shows an example to display an image

Comment: How can I prevent users from selecting a file outside of the base directory?

Comment: The easiest way would be to secure IIS for `Path traversals`. Also ensure that `robots.txt` exists and mentions what is allowed and not-allowed. You can also try **encoding** URLs